# Separating some subplots but not others; Python, Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I'm plotting a grid of subplots with matplotlib (v 1.4.2) in python (v 2.7.9).  I can manually adjust the spacing between the subplots, but I'd like different spacing for just some of the subplots.  The final figure I'm hoping for is a grid of 2x5 subplots on the left, a grid of 2x5 subplots on the right, and a space in the middle.

The code I'm using to control the figure layout is below:

```
figw, figh = 16.5, 15.0 #18.5, 15.0
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=5, sharex=False, 
                         sharey=True, figsize=(figw, figh))

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0, wspace=0.2, left=1/figw,
                    right=1-2./figw, bottom=1/figh, top=1-2./figh)
```

When I change `wspace` I get 4 columns all equally spaced.  Is there a way of changing `wspace` in such a way that it's 0 between columns 0 and 1, x between 1 and 2, and 0 between 2 and 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can if you use `GridSpec` as described here in the docs: [Adjust GridSpec layout](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout)

**Edit:**

A sample code, modified from example above, of how it should look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

f = plt.figure()

plt.suptitle("Different vertical spacings")

gs1 = GridSpec(5, 2)
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0])
#Add the other subplots for left hand side

gs2 = GridSpec(5, 2)
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98, wspace=0)
ax11 = plt.subplot(gs2[0,0])
ax12 = plt.subplot(gs2[1,0])
#Add the other subplots for right hand side

plt.show()
```

Haven't been able to test it so hope it works.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers as links can change, get broken, or the content linked to be updated outside of SO's control.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the example, I was having trouble getting to grips with info in the link.